# What is an example of a decidable language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, decision-problem

I know that if a language is regular or context free, the language is decidable. However, if a language is decidable does that imply that it is also regular or context free?

Comment: Your question title doesn't make much sense. You already know that every regular language is decidable; surely you can come up with some examples of those?

Answer (score 3):

No.

As an example of a language that is decidable but does not have a context-free grammar is the language over the decimal digits that only contains the prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$\{a^nb^nc^n \ |\ n\geq 0\}$ is one of the most famous non context-free languages. Consequently, it is also non regular. It is clearly decidable.